# Subquery optimization in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table where I store a lot of products. I used this query for getting all products whose prices are greater than average:

```
select price, name from product
where price > (select avg(price) from compra)
```

Since I have a lot of products, I need to optimize the query. Any help?

Comment: This query will never perform well, because you have to look at the prices for all products before you can return any of them. Your best option here is probably to keep a materialized view with the average, or approximate average, cached in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with query as (
select avg(price) as ave from product)

select price, name
from product p2, query
where p2.price > query.ave
```

Comment: It worked, EXPLAIN ANALYZE showed lower time when executing this query.

Comment: Shouldn't make much difference. Odd.

Comment: The same plan, though? Possibly benefiting from data caching if it was executed immediately after the other code, which would explain the performance improvement.

Comment: It depends on the amount of rows. "with" clausule allows executing the subquery just once instead of executing it for each row.